# Ошибка при загрузке модели keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Форум не даёт поздороваться, есть модель keras, которая сохраняется через **model.save()**
В этой модели используется самописная функция потерь:

```
def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(y_true * K.square(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(1 - y_pred, 0)))
model.compile(loss=contrastive_loss, optimizer=rms)
```

При обучении модели никаких проблем не возникает, но при загрузке модели:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("model.h5")
```

Летит ошибка: **ValueError: Unknown loss function:contrastive_loss**
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить

Comment: а что вам мешает определить такую же функцию __перед__ тем как загружать модель или же импортировать эту функцию из вашего модуля?

Comment: Модель компилируется, обучается и только потом загружается

Comment: Или я Вас неправильно понял

Comment: Ошибка же говорит, что функция « contrastive_loss» не определена/неизвестна. Вот и создайте эту функцию __перед вызовом__ “ model = load_model("model.h5")”